# Creating Maven archetype using required properties

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

I have created my own archetype which defines in archetype-metadata.xml a required property:

```
<requiredProperty key="version.wildfly">
    <defaultValue>16.0.0.Final</defaultValue>
</requiredProperty>
```

This property needs to be used in src/main/resources/archetype-resources/pom.xml as a property:

```
<properties>
    <version.server.bom>${version.wildfly}</version.server.bom>
</properties>
```

Indeed, when I create a project using this archetype, I'm being asked to confirm the default value for the property:

```
version.wildfly: 16.0.0.Final
 Y: : Y
```

However, in the generated project's pom.xml, it is not specified anywhere to use this property. The pom.xml merely contains:

```
<properties>
    <version.server.bom>${version.wildfly}</version.server.bom>
</properties>
```

And thus the build fails. Did I use any wrong pattern to inject the property in the pom.xml ?
Thanks

Comment: For an archetype, you need to define which files are "filtered" and which are not in the respective xml file. Furthermore, you may need to do some escaping since ${} also has a meaning in Maven (not only in velocity, which is used for the archetype). Sorry to be a bit vague, but I am not in the office now and have no immediate example at hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use **dot**, try `version-wildfly`.

looks like archetype consider dot-split property as internal use. see [Custom Properties](https://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/create-from-project-mojo.html)